# redshift adds escape character

Tags: csv, apache-spark, amazon-redshift

I am using spark-csv to convert a dataframe to CSV before I can load in into a redshift table. The spark-csv adds a backslash to escape the double quotes which is what I would expect. But when the copy command when it tries to load into redshift, it adds a backsplash to backsplash. How can I prevent it?

Here is a sample code:

```
df= sqlContext.createDataFrame([("1A", 123456, "first example"), ("1B", 123457, "It's a \"problem\"")], ['id', 'time', 'xstr'])

+---+------+----------------+
| id|  time|            xstr|
+---+------+----------------+
| 1A|123456|   first example|
| 1B|123457|It's a "problem"|
+---+------+----------------+

df.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "false")\
.option("quoteMode", "NON_NUMERIC")\
.save(fname)
```

RS Copy command:
    COPY xxxx  FROM YYYY  delimiter ','  FORMAT CSV

It errors out and the STL_LOAD_ERRORS table contains this:

```
1B,123457,"It's a \\"problem\\""
```

How do I prevent redshift from escaping an escape character?

Comment: BTW, you probably also want to use `REMOVEQUOTES` to take the outer quotes off your text strings.

Comment: Good catch. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including the [ESCAPE](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-escape) keyword in your COPY statement, e.g.

```
COPY xxxx FROM YYYY 
delimiter ',' 
FORMAT CSV
ESCAPE
;
```

Comment: Adding escape gave a error message that ESCAPE is not compatible with CSV. I removed format CSV and went through fine. Thanks!